# Wrapper for SQL and SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I am trying to expand an application that was originally designed with an sqlite database, to also interface with an sql server.  My initial thought was to make a wrapper class to handle these transactions.  With a Sqlselect function for returning data and a SQLexecute function to do non-query transactions.

My initial stab is something like this:

```
public static class Sqlwrapper
{

    public static int Sqltype = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Fills a datatable with the result of the select command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmdstring"> Connection string </param>
    /// <param name="dt">Datatable to be filled</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true if successful, false if there is any issues.</returns>
    public static bool Sqlselect(string cmdstring, out DataTable dt)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();

        if (Sqltype == 0)
        {
            SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Resources\\DB.sqlite;Version=3");
            try
            {
                c.Open();
                SQLiteDataAdapter a = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmdstring, c);
                a.Fill(dt);
                c.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                c.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Server=Server;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            try
            {
                c.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstring, c);
                a.Fill(dt);
                c.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                c.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a sql command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmdstring">sql command string</param>
    /// <returns>True for success.</returns>
    public static bool Sqlexecute(string cmdstring)
    {
        if (Sqltype == 0)
        {
            SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Resources\\DB.sqlite;Version=3");
            try
            {
                c.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdstring, c);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                c.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                c.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Server=Server;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            try
            {
                c.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstring, c);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                c.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                c.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this seems to work, but there are some issues I am running into, for example.  Pulling from the sqlserver I'll need to add in a username, for the local database we are not sending that data.

Is my method of passing a command string and/or getting out a datatable a good practice?  Is there an easier method I am overlooking?

thanks!

Edit:
Here is the second implementation:

```
public class DbManager
{
    public IDbProvider DbProvider;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sqltype">An integer to set which database type to use, defaults to 0 for sqlite, set to 1 for sql server.</param>
    public DbManager(int sqltype = 0)
    {
        if (sqltype == 0)
        {
            DbProvider = new SqliteWrapper();
        }
        else
        {
            DbProvider = new SqlWrapper();
        }
    }
}

public interface IDbProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills a datatable with the result of the select command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmdstring"> Connection string </param>
    /// <param name="dt">Datatable to be filled</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true if successful, false if there is any issues.</returns>
    bool Sqlselect(string cmdstring, out DataTable dt);

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a sql command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmdstring">sql command string</param>
    /// <returns>True for success.</returns>
    bool Sqlexecute(string cmdstring);
}

public class SqliteWrapper : IDbProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills a datatable with the result of the select command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmdstring"> Connection string </param>
    /// <param name="dt">Datatable to be filled</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true if successful, false if there is any issues.</returns>
    public bool Sqlselect(string cmdstring, out DataTable dt)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Resources\\DB.sqlite;Version=3");
        try
        {
            c.Open();
            SQLiteDataAdapter a = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmdstring, c);
            a.Fill(dt);
            c.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            c.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a sql command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmdstring">sql command string</param>
    /// <returns>True for success.</returns>
    public bool Sqlexecute(string cmdstring)
    {
        SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Resources\\DB.sqlite;Version=3");
        try
        {
            c.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdstring, c);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            c.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            c.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class SqlWrapper : IDbProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills a datatable with the result of the select command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmdstring"> Connection string </param>
    /// <param name="dt">Datatable to be filled</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true if successful, false if there is any issues.</returns>
    public bool Sqlselect(string cmdstring, out DataTable dt)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Server=Server;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        try
        {
            c.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstring, c);
            a.Fill(dt);
            c.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            c.Close();
            return false;
        }

    }
    public bool Sqlexecute(string cmdstring)
    {


        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Server=Server;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        try
        {
            c.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstring, c);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            c.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            c.Close();
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, every class in the ADO.NET framework has a common parent used by all providers. So you should be able to get around the fact that the application uses two kinds of databases just by using a Factory pattern (http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) or an Abstract Factory (http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx).

This would insure that you don't need two implementation of the wrappers. For example :

```
public abstract class SqlFactory
{
    public abstract DbConnection CreateConnection();

    public abstract DataAdapter CreateAdapter(string command, DbConnection connection);

}

public class SqlLiteFactory : SqlFactory
{
    public override DbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Resources\\DB.sqlite;Version=3");
    }

    public override DataAdapter CreateAdapter(string command, DbConnection connection)
    {
        return new SQLiteDataAdapter(command, connection as SQLiteConnection);
    }
}

public class MSSqlFactory : SqlFactory
{
    public override DbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING HERE");
    }

    public override DataAdapter CreateAdapter(string command, DbConnection connection)
    {
        return new SqlDataAdapter(command, connection as SqlConnection);
    }
}

//Composite and Singleton class...
public class SqlHandler : SqlFactory
{
    private static SqlHandler _instance;

    private SqlLiteFactory _sqlLiteFactory;
    private MSSqlFactory _msSqlFactory;

    //Singleton pattern.
    public static SqlHandler Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new SqlHandler();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private SqlHandler()
    {
        _sqlLiteFactory = new SqlLiteFactory();
        _msSqlFactory = new MSSqlFactory();
    }

    public override DbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        //Some code determining if better to use SqlLite or MS SQL.
        if (useSqlLite)
        {
            return _sqlLiteFactory.CreateConnection();
        }
        else
        {
            return _msSqlFactory.CreateConnection();
        }
    }

    public override DataAdapter CreateAdapter(string command, DbConnection connection)
    {
        //Some code determining if better to use SqlLite or MS SQL.
        if (useSqlLite)
        {
            return _sqlLiteFactory.CreateAdapter(command, connection);
        }
        else
        {
            return _msSqlFactory.CreateAdapter(command, connection);
        }
    }
}
```

So when you would need to invoke anything database related in your wrapper, you can just do :

```
DbConnection c = SqlHandler.Instance.CreateConnection();
```

This way also allows you to implement easily new databases.

PS : For your connection strings, I would recommend you use the App.config file to set it. If anything changes in the future, you will be able to change the database without having to recompile your application.

Comment: Your example DbConnection c = SqlHandler.CreateConnection(); doesn't seem to work as stated, do I need to instantiate an instance of sqlhandler first? Which I can't seem to do because the constructor is private.  Should that be public or the class be static?

Comment: You're right. I didn't invoke the Instance property. I edited the code  and it should now work. As for the constructor, it's normal that it's private since we are using using a Singleton pattern and we only want one instance of the class. And if we make the class static, we break the composite pattern since we won't be able to inherit from `SqlFactory` anymore (static inheritance is illegal in C#).

Comment: Thanks!  It seems to work great!  Just one more question, I am trying to implement your suggestion for moving the connection strings to the app.config.  I have added the Following lines:  
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Sqlite" connectionString="Data Source=Resources\\DB.sqlite;Version=3" providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
    <add name="Sql" connectionString="Server=Server;Database=QA;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

But I get an error: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Application' threw an exception.  Any Ideas?

Comment: I will refer you to the MSDN page for App.config files : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx. It might just be an error on where you put your tags. Have you included it in the `<configuration>` tag ?

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem, someone else added a connection strings tag much lower, I think having two connection strings was giving me the error.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not to create interface of IDatabaseProvider and create two classes for each type. above you can create class of DBManager which can call either both of the object or only one

Comment: Would it be possible to link in a tutorial or documentation where I can learn how to do this?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I though you were specifying specific interfaces and classes.  I see what you mean now.

Comment: Quick question, at the moment my thought was to just pass a string for the sql command.  the issue is passing parameters, both sql and sqlite have different kinds of parameters, would it be best to pass a command string and an array of string parameters which each class could then parse into their types of parameters?  Thanks!

Comment: I have added what I believe to be what you are suggesting, It seems to be working.  Is this indeed what you were suggesting?